# How do LDMOS datasheets label current draw through the gate?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, datasheet, dac

I'm trying to figure out how much current is required to bias a FET's Vgs so I can choose a DAC to set the gain.  If I understand correctly, very little is required, but I couldn't find something obvious on the datasheet.

I'm looking at the [NXP MRF300AN 300W LDMOS](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/MRF300AN-1381586.pdf), what would that gain-source current be labeled?

Comment: No (well, maybe a few picoamps, if you include leakage) steady state current is needed, but quite a lot of dynamic current can be required. This is why gate drivers exist.

Comment: @Hearth, since you mentioned a gate driver, would you take a look at this question too? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/603146/256265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I<sub>GSS</sub> is the gate source leakage current, and is specified with a max of 1 uA. This figure is probably a test equipment limit rather than a true device parameter.

This is only specified when the device is off, with 5 V across both GS and GD junctions, as that's the easiest mode to measure this current.

The way FETs work, this current is not going to increase with the device operating, except for temperature that is. It would have been nice to see a graph of I<sub>GSS</sub> versus temperature in the data sheet.

Comment: Wow, tiny.  Really 1uA? Almost hard to believe but makes sense since its an enhancement mode device.  So correct me if I misunderstood, but it seems that any DAC should be able to drive the gate!

Comment: @KJ7LNW It's because it's an insulated gate, not because it's enhancement mode--depletion mode MOSFETs have very low gate current as well. The gate of a MOSFET is best modelled as a capacitor.