# When should you use a gate driver, and how do you choose one?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, amplifier, gate-driving, low-noise-amplifier

I'm building an amp using the [NXP MRF300AN 300W LDMOS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/603052/256265) RF power amplifier device and was originally planning to use a DAC to drive the gate bias until [@Hearth mentioned that I should use a gate driver](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/603052/256265). A quick search for ["gate driver" on Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/power-management-ics/gate-drivers/) turned up 6000+ results, so help!

Questions:

1. What do you look for in a gate driver to drive an LDMOS FET high-power RF amp?
2. Do you need a gate driver for smaller amplifiers like LNA's?

Comment: Gate drivers are usually necessary (and optimised for) switching applications, but driving the gate from a DAC sounds like you aren't switching. Understand *why* gate drivers are necessary ... Cgs + Cgd * gain ... and you'll see that in a linear application you need a buffer capable of driving capacitive loads.

Comment: That's an RF MOSFET (perhaps @Hearth didn't check?)  What is your intended use?  Generally if you're designing an amplifier you don't use a gate driver as the term is used when you're buying chips.

Comment: @TimWescott, the intended use gain control of a 300W power amp at 146MHz by adjusting the gate bias.

Comment: @user_1818839, so are gate drivers not used for RF MOSFETs?

Comment: Gate drivers are used for switching applications, which the vast majority of uses for MOSFETs are. If you're driving from a DAC, that tells me you're probably using the FET in a linear mode of operation, in which case the gate driver will be useless. Model the gate as a capacitor instead. And yes @TimWescott, I did not check--I have very little knowledge or familiarity with RF electronics and made a faulty assumption.

Comment: @Hearth: that's the answer.

Comment: Not sure you're going to be able to trim the gain without adversely impacting linearity.  Unless you're just planning on constant-envelope operation.

Comment: @TimWescott, gain would be trimmed to a set point and left alone.  The datasheet shows amp gain based on Vgs (and input power) to control the RF output power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gate drivers are used for switching applications, which the vast majority of uses for MOSFETs are. If you're driving from a DAC, that tells me you're probably using the FET in a linear mode of operation, in which case the gate driver will be useless. Model the gate as a capacitor instead.